# Android: How deploy to Fabric (Beta by CrashLytics) from console by Gradle?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics, google-fabric

Android Studio 2.3.3
Plugin: Fabric for Android Studio.

If I want to deploy my **apk** to *Fabric* (**Beta by CrashLytics**).

So I use plugin **Fabric for Android Studio**

Here is the screenshot:

[image: Deploy to Fabric]

And I success deploy to *Fabric* and see my distributive (**apk**) on **Beta by CrashLytics**.

OK. It's work fine.

Now I want to do same by **Gradle** from console.
How I can do this?

Comment: https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install check this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the documentation at https://docs.fabric.io/android/beta/gradle.html

If you want to distribute your app via Gradle, make sure you’re on version 1.11.4 or higher of the Gradle tool and run the following command:

```
gradlew assembleRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease
```